# No extensions menu in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have followed this tutorial from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-the-vsix-project-template?view=vs-2019

I am trying to create a visual studio extension but I cannot make it appear, I have made what the tutorial said, like adding my extension to the menu group:

```
<Groups>
  <Group guid="guidTestCommandPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidTestCommandPackageCmdSet" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

My problem is that I cannot find the extension anywhere. Actually, I cannot find the "Extensions" menu anywhere. Under the "Tools" menu there is a submenu called "Extensions and updates" but that is not it. Where is the "Extensions" Menu in visual studio 2017?

Here is my top menu:
[image: Menus]

Here is my right click menu when I right click on a project:
[image]

This is the second tutorial I am trying from Microsoft but when they tell you to look for the Extension they say:

> 10. Select Manage Extensions (on the Extensions menu)

Which does not exist.

Tools menu (please notice the "Extensions and updates" menu, which is not what I am looking for and it does not have the same functionality as stated in the Microsoft tutorial):
[image: Tools menu]

Comment: I already looked at tools but its not there

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: [Visual Studio 2017 Extension development tutorial, Part 2: Add Menu Item](https://michaelscodingspot.com/visual-studio-2017-extension-development-tutorial-part-2-add-menu-item/)

Comment: I have done something similar from the Microsoft Tutorial

Comment: @asp.netCoreProblem Can you try running Visual Studio as Administrator and check again.

Comment: Same menus when running as admin

Comment: Does anyone here have the Extensions menu?

Comment: You're looking a tutorial for VS2019, but using VS2017, that menu changed location. The "Extensions and Updates" under Tools, as you've found, is the **exact equivalent** in 2017. Just use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it back by right-clicking on the menu bar and selecting customize at the bottom. next select the commands tab and change the menu bar to tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please look under Tools -> Extentions

Comment: That is my problem, there is no "Extensions" under tools.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot from your Tools menu (between Team and Test)?

Comment: i have now added it